# How can I cache private NuGet packages on Azure DevOps?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-devops, nuget

I followed [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/caching-nuget?view=azure-devops) on how to cache NuGet packages in an Azure DevOps pipeline.

It works up until it reaches my own custom made NuGet packages. It's failing with the following error:

`##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(NU1101: Unable to find package <My Package>. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\library-pack, NuGetOrg`

I don't want to upload my NuGet packages to NuGet Org. How can I configure this to recognize that these packages are from a local repository?

Comment: Host your own private nuget server like BaGet

Answer (score 0):

I see from the error message, you haven't configured any package sources, so only nuget.org is being used.

Assuming you published your private package to Azure Artifacts, their getting stated guide has instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/get-started-nuget?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows

The "Connect to feed" section should be of particular interest to you.

You should create a nuget.config in your repo root (it's acceptable to be in a subdirectory, only if your .sln file is in the same subdirectory). The contents of the nuget.config file is provided to your by the Azure DevOps website, and an example can be seen in the linked documentation.